# How to pass image from url to another view contoller using sd webimage framework swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage

I have a collection view cell in first view controller which has imageview fetched from url using sd webimage third party library.This image is a thumbnail image.I want to pass the actual image to another view controller in didselectitemat of first view controller.The code is as follows:

```
 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return subcategoryArray.count

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        print("inside cell for item at ")

        let cell:SubCategoryCollectionViewCell = self.collectionview3.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryCollectionViewCell

        if defaultAnimalArray.count - 1 >= indexPath.row
         {
           let item = self.defaultAnimalArray[indexPath.row]
           cell.subThumbImg?.image = UIImage(named: item as! String)
         }

        else
        {
            //If now defaultAnimalArray.count = 8, indexPath = 8 , But array = 0...4, then,
            let item1 = self.subcategoryArray[indexPath.row - self.defaultAnimalArray.count]
             self.subcatthumbimagelink = (item1 as AnyObject).object(forKey: "SubcategoryThumb") as! String
            cell.subThumbImg.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.subcatthumbimagelink), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"),options: SDWebImageOptions(), completed: {(image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> Void in
                print("image loaded")
            })
          }


        return cell

    }
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("image selected for coloring")


    if defaultAnimalArray.count - 1 >= indexPath.row
    {
        print("indexpath selected is \(indexPath.row)")
         let item = self.animalcategoryImages[indexPath.row]
        var drawVC  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawingViewController") as! DrawingViewController
        drawVC.selectedimage = UIImage(named:item)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(drawVC, animated: true)
    }

    else
    {
         print("indexpath selected in else loop is \(indexPath.row)")


     let item1 = self.subcategoryArray[indexPath.row - 10]
        print("subcategory count after manipulation is \(self.subcategoryArray)")
        print("count of item1 \((item1 as AnyObject).count)")
       print("item1 is \(item1)")
        self.subcategoryimagelink = (item1 as AnyObject).object(forKey: "SubcategoryImage") as! String
        print("category image link is \(self.subcategoryimagelink)")
        self.ImageviewMain.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.subcategoryimagelink))

        var drawVC  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawingViewController") as! DrawingViewController
       drawVC.selectedimage = self.ImageviewMain.image
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(drawVC, animated: true)

    }
```

The subcategory count is addition of array from url and a array which is default.Kindly help me how to pass the image from url which is in cell to another view controller.

Comment: In my opinion you should pass the url instead of the image to the next view controller. Because there is a good chance that when user redirect to the another view controller the image is still not loaded in the image view due to the asynchronous call of image downloading and you will never be able to display the actual image in next view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass only image **url** string instead of **UIImage object**

```
var drawVC  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawingViewController") as! DrawingViewController
drawVC.imageURL = self.subcatthumbimagelink // you can also pass string from array 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(drawVC, animated: true)
```

**In DrawingViewController**

```
 var imageURL : String?
 self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:imageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"),options: SDWebImageOptions(), completed: {(image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> Void in
                    print("image loaded")
                })
```

Comment: The next view controller does not have imageview, it has UIImage only which is on top of scrollview.

Comment: you don't want to display this image ?

Comment: if dont wont display then you can get image as like : **let data = try? Data(contentsOf: self. imageURL)
  selectedimage =UIImage(data: data!)!**

Comment: i shall try it out

Comment: @jyotsnapandey Without ImageView how would you display your UIImage in your scroll view. UIImage contains the data for an image whereas UIImageView is a custom view meant to display the UIImage.